# JD-GUI and Boomerang Deompilers Installation for Ubuntu

Tags: java, compiler, assembler

I am currently taking a Cyber Security Course online and the instructor uses both, JD-GUI and Boomerang Decompilers. Therefore, I would like to get help on how to install those for Ubuntu. I have looked up videos and other forums on installation guides and they have not been pretty helpful, or at least understandable for me. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just download them and run the JAR file with `java -jar filename.jar`

Comment: @AndroidDev when I try it, it says `Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile jd-gui.jar`

Comment: Did you `cd` into the directory first?

Comment: Yes @AndroidDev

Comment: Have you tried doing `chmod +x`on it?

Comment: Hi @AndroidDev! Thank you for the help :D I am not sure what it was but I got it working at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Boomerand but for JD-GUI you need to install java runtime environment first

```
sudo apt install default-jre
```

Then you need to download the decompiler from [here](http://jd.benow.ca/#jd-gui-download).

Install the deb package using:

```
sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb
```